# Inserting values in SQL from different table and userinput

Tags: c#, sql

firstoff I want to say that I am very new to programming in general, so i apologize if I'm making very obvious mistakes (infact i certainly am). I've been looking around about this issue for a while now, but can't find anything that applies to my specific problem.

I am trying to make a Studentmanager in C# where someone could have a List of their classes, what students are in those classes and enter all their grades.
For now I have 2 tables in SQL "Klassen"(classes) and "Schüler"(students) and i have a Listbox that displays all entries in "Klassen" and a listbox that displays all students within that class.
I want to be able to add a student to a class through a textbox, the Name of the students is the text in the textbox and the classId(which i am using to link the students to what class they are in) should be the Id(Primarykey) of the class i have selected.

I hope I discribed my issue well enough.
Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to help :)

```
private void TxbSchüler_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {

                try
                {
                    string query = "insert into Schüler values (@Name, @KlassenId";
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txbSchüler.Text.ToString());
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KlassenId", listClasses.SelectedValue);
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    sqlConnection.Close();
                    ShowStudent();
                    ShowClass();
                }
            }
```

Comment: listClasses.SelectedValue.id ?

Comment: Hi @BeneTan, can you elaborate what is the error you faced exactly?

Comment: Do not delete your question when you get your answer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions.